# Text not appearing in tableview controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a tableview controller as my initial view. I added some text into it and it's not appearing.  First i added some labels, and none of them was appearing, i thought maybe it was a constraint problem.  So i added constraints and still didn't work.    Then I made the cells basic rather then custom.  In basic, it gives you text for you. And still the text isn't appearing. How can i fix this?

Note: This is a new project, I have tested this on a real device and have the same issue.

Comment: add a datasource to your table view and return a cell from `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: Add your code, we are not mind readers

Comment: @Rob85 i guess you're not a good reader either... Their is no code... It's a whole new project. i just added some labels into the project and their not displaying.

Comment: Are only add labels to current cell in TableViewController at Storyboard?

Comment: @asdf if your project runs without code i want some of your wizardry, when  you create a new project and start adding things via the Interface builder all it is doing is adding code in for you, so you should be able to open your viewController and see the code it has created

Answer (score 0):

The table is created with the default prototypes of cells (Content field is Dynamics Prototypes) that need to create and add from the code. If you want to make a static cell, you need to do this in storyboard:

1. Select TableView 
   [image]
2. Set Content field in Attributes Inspector to `Static Cells`
   [image]
3. Add your labels to Static cells
   [image]